# How to generate the `Release` file on a local package repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, packaging, deb

### *CONTEXT*

With a local package repository, I'm able to provide my APT instances with a set of software packages and configurations from a server which I control, allowing any client to install this software using just the normal `apt install` command (providing the repository is added to their `/etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/}`).

For my attempt at creating a local package repository, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.bipmedia.com/blog/tutorial/how-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository) on bipmedia.com, which roughly consists of:

1. Generate the .deb
2. Store the .deb on an Apache2 web server
3. Generate a Package.gz file

#### My Attempt

##### Generating the binary package file

To generate the .deb, the software files are required, a DEBIAN folder with metadata is generated and the following command compiles the code and assembles the package:

`dpkg-deb --build [`*`source code tree with DEBIAN directory`*`]`

##### Serve repository files with Apache2 server

*I'm skipping this part as it's unrelated to the problem I'm seeking to solve with this question.*

##### Generating a Packages.gz file (repository metadata)

With the an open shell instance whose working directory is the Apache server root folder containing the `.deb` file from above, I called:

`dpkg-scanpackages debian /dev/null | gzip -9c >debian/Packages.gz`

### *PROBLEM*

Calling `apt update` on the client machine, it complains with:

```bsh
W: The repository 'http://example.com packages/ Release' does not have a Release file.
```

This necessary file is missing in my local repository. It seems to be a register of package checksums, but after searching on the Internet, my very limited understanding of the topic kept me from being able to find out how to generate it.

---

***Note:*** My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file does have the following line:

`deb http://example.com packages/`

### *QUESTION*

How do I generate the `Release` file for a local APT package repository?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of ways of going about this; I use `apt-ftparchive`.

1. Create an `aptftp.conf` file in the root of your repository:

   ```
   APT::FTPArchive::Release {
     Origin "Your origin";
     Label "Your label";
     Suite "unstable";
     Codename "sid";
     Architectures "amd64 i386 source";
     Components "main";
     Description "Your description";
   };
   ```

   with the appropriate values (change “Origin”, “Label”, “Description” at least, and adjust “Architectures” to match the binaries you host).
2. Create a matching `aptgenerate.conf` file alongside:

   ```
   Dir::ArchiveDir ".";
   Dir::CacheDir ".";
   TreeDefault::Directory "pool/";
   TreeDefault::SrcDirectory "pool/";
   Default::Packages::Extensions ".deb";
   Default::Packages::Compress ". gzip bzip2";
   Default::Sources::Compress ". gzip bzip2";
   Default::Contents::Compress "gzip bzip2";

   BinDirectory "dists/unstable/main/binary-amd64" {
     Packages "dists/unstable/main/binary-amd64/Packages";
     Contents "dists/unstable/Contents-amd64";
     SrcPackages "dists/unstable/main/source/Sources";
   };

   BinDirectory "dists/unstable/main/binary-i386" {
     Packages "dists/unstable/main/binary-i386/Packages";
     Contents "dists/unstable/Contents-i386";
     SrcPackages "dists/unstable/main/source/Sources";
   };

   Tree "dists/unstable" {
     Sections "main"; # contrib non-free";
     Architectures "amd64 i386 source";
   };
   ```

   (removing `i386` if you don’t need that).
3. In your repository, clear the database:

   ```
   rm -f packages-i386.db packages-amd64.db
   ```
4. Generate the package catalogs:

   ```
   apt-ftparchive generate -c=aptftp.conf aptgenerate.conf
   ```
5. Generate the `Release` file:

   ```
   apt-ftparchive release -c=aptftp.conf dists/unstable >dists/unstable/Release
   ```
6. Sign it:

   ```
   gpg -u yourkeyid -bao dists/unstable/Release.gpg dists/unstable/Release
   gpg -u yourkeyid --clear-sign --output dists/unstable/InRelease dists/unstable/Release
   ```

   (with the appropriate id instead of `yourkeyid`).

Whenever you make a change to the repository, you need to run steps 3 to 6 again.

Comment: Can you use something like ` dpkg-scanpackages` rather than `apt-ftparchive`?

Comment: @Toby you can use `dpkg-scanpackages` to generate the package catalogs, but it won’t handle `Release` for you. The simple option nowadays is probably `aptly`; I should re-write this answer using that.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I should have said earlier, I was looking for a cross platform tool which `apt-ftparchive` seems like it's not. So `aptly` sounds good for me and I'll read up on creating the packages. I'm assuming the signing is separate anyway.

Comment: I have done exactly this, with `focal` instead of `unstable` everywhere, and `amd64` only, and my custom deb file is in `dists/focal/main/binary-amd64`, but when I run step 4, may `Packages` file in `dists/focal/main/binary-amd64` is empty, zero size. And if I try to install the binary on another computer, it does not find the package...